# Como posso adicionar um array dentro de array?

Tags: php

Eu preciso de um array multidimensional que vai ser composto de informações do banco, mas não to conseguindo adicionar essas informações. Eu não sei explicar muito bem, então vou mostrar.

Assim que eu quero:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [valor_apostado] => 100
            [valor_final] => 817
            [id_aposta] => 1022
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [timeApostado] => Motherwell
                        [partidaApostada] => Motherwell x Hearts
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [timeApostado] => Hearts
                        [partidaApostada] => Pandora x Hearts
                    )

            )
)
```

Mas ele vem assim:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [valor_apostado] => 100
            [valor_final] => 817
            [id_aposta] => 1022
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [timeApostado] => Motherwell
                    [partidaApostada] => Motherwell x Hearts
                )

        )
```

A outra parte do array dentro do array não é exibido.

Meu código:

```
$idAnt = 0;
$array = "";
$i = 0;
$n = 0;
while($dado = $pegar->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $valor_apostado = $dado["valor_apostado"];
    $valor_final = $dado["valor_final"];
    $tipo_aposta = $dado["tipo_aposta"];
    $time = $dado["nome_time"];
    $idAposta = $dado["id_aposta"];

    if($idAposta == $idAnt) {
      $x[$n] = array(
        "timeApostado" => $tipo_aposta,
        "partidaApostada" => $time
      );
      $n++;
    } else {
      $n = 0;
      $x = array(
        "valor_apostado" => $valor_apostado,
        "valor_final" =>$valor_final,
        "id_aposta" => $idAposta,
        $n => array(
          "timeApostado" => $tipo_aposta,
          "partidaApostada" => $time
        )
      );
      $array[$i]= $x;
      $i++;
      $n++;
    }
    $idAnt = $idAposta;

}
```

Comment: Quando você faz a pesquisa no banco de dados, todas as informações são trazidas? Se sim, tenta fazer isto: `$x[$n][]`

Comment: Sim, todas de uma única vez. Vou tentar!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu código me parece correto, estando apenas com erro na hora de atribuir os valores para os array. Você está resetando o contador sempre que existe uma resposta igual. Logo após o comando `else` remova a condição `$n = 0;`.

Seu codigo ficaria assim:

```
  if($idAposta == $idAnt) {
      $x[$n] = array(
        "timeApostado" => $tipo_aposta,
        "partidaApostada" => $time
      );
      $n++;
    } else {
      $x = array(
```

Comment: Na verdade, eu preciso que o $n seja igual a zero novamente porque pode existir as duas formas, entende? Pode existir apenas um array filho dentro do array pai ou vários arrays filhos dentro do array pai. Então se não existir mais arrays filhos dentro do pai depois que ele já adicionou todos os filhos existentes, o código precisa acrescentar mais um pai com seus próprios filhos dentro do array avô.

Comment: Por isso existe o if também, pq se o novo id_aposta for diferente do anterior, então ele vai acrescentar um novo array pai

Comment: @Krint, é possível fazer isso que você quer, mas vai demandar um algoritmo um pouco mais complexo. Uma solução mais fácil é manter as alterações que eu sugeri e passar a ordenar a sua pesquisa no banco de dados. Desta forma não tem como vir novamente um filho de outro pai.

Answer (score 2):

Você também pode alterar seu código para usar o `$idAposta` como índice.

```
$array = array();
while($dado = $pegar->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $valor_apostado = $dado["valor_apostado"];
    $valor_final = $dado["valor_final"];
    $tipo_aposta = $dado["tipo_aposta"];
    $time = $dado["nome_time"];
    $idAposta = $dado["id_aposta"];

    if(array_key_exists($idAposta, $array)) {
        $array[$idAposta][] = array(
            "timeApostado"      => $tipo_aposta,
            "partidaApostada"   => $time
        );
    } else {
        $array[$idAposta] = array(
            "valor_apostado"    => $valor_apostado,
            "valor_final"       =>$valor_final,
            "id_aposta"         => $idAposta,
            0 => array(
                "timeApostado"  => $tipo_aposta,
                "partidaApostada" => $time
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Não funcionou da forma que eu precisava